# Python Kivy - Call methods across different class

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to coding, a few months with Python and trying to wrap my head around Kivy. I think there is a simple solution to this but I am struggling when it comes to calling a method in one class from another. Not even sure if this is possible, my OOP wouldn't be very strong!!

Would appreciate if someone could explain this to me! I've looked online but still struggling to understand what I need to do.

i have a simple code that had a label and 3 toggle buttons, the label text changes to show how many toggle buttons are pressed. Below is the original code.

What I am trying to do create the toggle buttons using a loop so that the number of toggle buttons can be easily altered. i have achieved this but when I try and bind the method to the toggle button the code fails with. I also tried defining a method within the "Tbtn" class to call the Main.Counter() but this didn't work either.

The line

```
    self.bind(on_state = Main.counter())
```

in the **init** of the toggle button is where i am going wrong I think.

Any help and even an explanation would be great. Not the first time I have been stuck on this!! Thanks

Original Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class Tbtn(ToggleButton):
    pass

class Header_Box(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Counter(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Main(BoxLayout):
    count = NumericProperty()

    def counter(self,widget):
        toggles = []
        for child in self.ids.Seat_Box.children:
            if isinstance(child, ToggleButton):
                if child.state == 'down':
                    toggles.append(child.text)
        self.count = len(toggles)
        print(self.count)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

TestApp().run()
```

The KV file:

```
<Main>:
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"
        Header_Box:
            Label:
                text: str(root.count)

        Counter:
            id: Seat_Box            
            Tbtn:
                id: btn1
                on_state: root.counter(self)
            Tbtn:
                id: btn2
                on_state: root.counter(self)
            Tbtn:
                id: btn2
                on_state: root.counter(self)
```

Code with for Loop:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class Tbtn(ToggleButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bind(on_state = Main().counter())

class Header_Box(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Counter(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        for x in range(3):
            btn = Tbtn()
            self.add_widget(btn)

class Main(BoxLayout):
    count = NumericProperty()

    def counter(self,widget):
        toggles = []
        for child in self.ids.Seat_Box.children:
            if isinstance(child, ToggleButton):
                if child.state == 'down':
                    toggles.append(child.text)
        self.count = len(toggles)
        print(self.count)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

TestApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
<Main>:
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"
        Header_Box:
            Label:
                text: str(root.count)

        Counter:
            id: Seat_Box
```

Comment: Could you please edit your problematic code snippet with proper indentation in order to copy-paste directly ?

Comment: That should be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, **Remove**  `self.bind(on_state = Main().counter())`.

I suggest you to solve this in .kv side.

**Way 1-.kv side:**
Add this below your .kv file:

```
<Tbtn>:
    on_state: app.get_running_app().root.counter(self)
```

**Way 2-.py side:** Add this in Tbtn class.

```
def on_release(self):
    App.get_running_app().root.counter(self)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks!!Is there somewhere that has all the "secret" methods that are available in Kivy... All the searching I did and I didn't find get_running_app() or anything like it.... I find the Kivy docs a bit confusing, possibly because I am new enough to coding. Or is it just really the Kivy docs and thats it??

Comment: Actually i search examples to find my way but sometimes (less than searching) i read documentation :). After coding for a while, you'll see that you need to edit your codes at starting cuz of some situtation. For an example, i suggest you to code under `ScreenManager` so `Screen` classes. As button's `on_release` function like, screens have different functions and these can save your time. Main method, create widgets and access'em from in another classes. Also `KivyMD` is beautiful library for kivy theming and it has more understandable (with examples.) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answer already solved your issue, the following made me post this one.

> Any help and even an explanation would be great...

Technically the following line,

```py
self.bind(on_state = Main().counter())
```

is wrong for various reasons. Let's try to figure this out.

The method `on_state` is kind of generic one not a default [event](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#valid-expressions) (like `on_press` etc.). That's why `bind(on_state = some_callback)` won't work.

Again you did `Main().counter()` which actually creates a new instance of `Main` (which may or may not be related to the `root`, and here it's of course not) and assigned to its method.

It seems you want to just access one of `Main` widget's (which happens to be the `root` widget here) method.

Since you used `kvlang`, this could be done more efficiently as follows,

```py
<Tbtn>:
    on_state: app.root.counter()
```

You can find more about this in the [`kvlang` doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords).

Now in `.py` you just define the class along with some other changes,

```py
class Tbtn(ToggleButton):
    pass
.
.
.
class Main(BoxLayout):
    count = NumericProperty()

    def counter(self): # Pass no extra args as you haven't done in 'on_state' method.
        toggles = []
        .
        .
        .
```